# Dynamic-SQL: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','

Tags: sql-server, dynamic

I am getting the about error while trying to run the following SQL. I am trying to run a dynamic query with several different parameters. Any advice or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
/* ----- For Testing ----- */
DECLARE @StartDate NVARCHAR(10) = '04/01/2018',
        @EndDate NVARCHAR(10) = '04/01/2018',
        @Location NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Newcastle, Salt Creek',
        @DayType NVARCHAR(20) = 'Calendar',
        @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT S.SiteCode,
        S.Name AS Site_Name,
        L.Name,
        DATEADD(HOUR, (T.Period) + 1, P.DateData) AS PeriodEnding,
        SUM(T.Ins) AS SumOfIns,
        SUM(T.Outs) AS SumOfOuts
FROM dbo.Location L
    INNER JOIN dbo.Traffic T ON L.ID = T.LocationID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Publish P ON T.PublishID = P.ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Site S ON P.SiteID = S.ID
WHERE ((P.DateData) BETWEEN '+ @StartDate +' AND '+ @EndDate +')
    AND T.Ins > -1
    AND ((T.EditSequence) = 0)
    AND ((P.CanPublish) = 1)
    AND L.IsActive = 1
    AND (L.IsInternal = 0 OR L.IsInternal IS NULL)
    AND S.CustomerID = 1
    AND S.Name in (''' + REPLACE(@Location,',',''',''') + ''')
    AND ('+ @DayType +' = ''Calendar'')
    OR  ('+ @Location +' IN (LT.Name) AND '+ @DayType +' = ''Business'' AND (T.Period between 7 and 17))
GROUP BY S.SiteCode,
    S.Name,
    L.Name,
    DATEADD(HOUR, (T.Period)+1, P.DateData)
ORDER BY S.SiteCode,
        S.Name,
        L.Name,
        DATEADD(HOUR, (T.Period)+1, P.DateData)';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

---

Thanks again for all of the help. My code now looks like this...

```
DECLARE @StartDate NVARCHAR(10) = '04/01/2018',
@EndDate NVARCHAR(10) = '04/01/2018',
@Location NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Salt Creek,Madill',
@DayType NVARCHAR(12) = 'Calendar',
@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = '     
SELECT S.SiteCode,
S.Name AS Site_Name,
L.Name,
DATEADD(HOUR, (T.Period) + 1, P.DateData) AS PeriodEnding,
SUM(T.Ins) AS SumOfIns,
SUM(T.Outs) AS SumOfOuts
FROM dbo.Location L
    INNER JOIN dbo.Traffic T ON L.ID = T.LocationID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Publish P ON T.PublishID = P.ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Site S ON P.SiteID = S.ID
WHERE ((P.DateData) BETWEEN '''+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @StartDate, 109) +''' AND '''+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @EndDate, 109) +''')
    AND T.Ins > -1
    AND ((T.EditSequence) = 0)
    AND ((P.CanPublish) = 1)
    AND L.IsActive = 1
    AND (L.IsInternal = 0 OR L.IsInternal IS NULL)
    AND S.CustomerID = 1
    AND LTRIM(S.Name) in (''' + REPLACE(@Location,',',''',''') + ''')
    AND '+ @DayType +' = ''Calendar''
    OR (S.Name in (''' + REPLACE(@Location,',',''',''') + ''') AND '+ @DayType +' = ''Business'' AND T.Period between 7 and 17)
GROUP BY S.SiteCode,
    S.Name,
    L.Name,
    DATEADD(HOUR, (T.Period)+1, P.DateData)
ORDER BY S.SiteCode,
    S.Name,
    L.Name,
    DATEADD(HOUR, (T.Period)+1, P.DateData)';
print @sql

CREATE TABLE #DailyTracking  (Site_Code INT, Site_Name VARCHAR(50), Location_Name VARCHAR(50), PeriodEnding DATE, SumOfIns INT, SumOfOuts INT)
INSERT INTO #DailyTracking EXEC sp_executesql @sql

SELECT * FROM #DailyTracking

DROP TABLE #DailyTracking
```

I am getting the error - Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 20 Invalid column name 'Calendar'.

I am trying to use this stored procedure to create a report in SSRS. The problem is I am trying to pass the @DayType parameter to run the query between 2 separate time frames. If I declare the parameter within the dynamic SQL it will work but I don't know how to pass the parameter from the SSRS report to within the @sql dynamic sql. Any tips/advice? All of the help has been great.

Comment: you don't have single quotes for your dates. Use `PRINT @sql` instead of `EXEC` and see the resulting code

Comment: I'd consider parametrising that SQL as well. The way you are concatenating your strings at the moment leaves you wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: If you want to debug dynamically constructed code, you must **see** the code that you constructed. There are a number of problems - which become more evident when you can see the statement. Off the bat, I can see you have no object with the alias LT. Your usage of @Location is also not correct. Print the constructed string and debug it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
BETWEEN '+ @StartDate +' AND '+ @EndDate +')
```

should be

```
BETWEEN '''+ @StartDate +''' AND '''+ @EndDate +''')
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am still getting the same "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','." message.

Comment: Try double checking this line:

OR  ('+ @Location +' IN (LT.Name) AND

it looks like it should read:

LT.Name IN (''' + REPLACE(@Location,',',''',''') + ''')

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like below

```
DECLARE @StartDate NVARCHAR(10) = '04/01/2018',
        @EndDate NVARCHAR(10) = '04/01/2018',
        @Location NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Newcastle, Salt Creek',
        @DayType NVARCHAR(20) = 'Calendar',
        @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT S.SiteCode,
        S.Name AS Site_Name,
        L.Name,
        DATEADD(HOUR, (T.Period) + 1, P.DateData) AS PeriodEnding,
        SUM(T.Ins) AS SumOfIns,
        SUM(T.Outs) AS SumOfOuts
FROM dbo.Location L
    INNER JOIN dbo.Traffic T ON L.ID = T.LocationID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Publish P ON T.PublishID = P.ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Site S ON P.SiteID = S.ID
WHERE ((P.DateData) BETWEEN '''+ @StartDate +''' AND '''+ @EndDate +''')
    AND T.Ins > -1
    AND ((T.EditSequence) = 0)
    AND ((P.CanPublish) = 1)
    AND L.IsActive = 1
    AND (L.IsInternal = 0 OR L.IsInternal IS NULL)
    AND S.CustomerID = 1
    AND S.Name in (''' + REPLACE(@Location,',',''',''') + ''')
    AND ('+ @DayType +' = ''Calendar'')
    OR (S.Name in (''' + REPLACE(@Location,',',''',''') + ''') AND '+ @DayType +' = ''Business'' AND (T.Period between 7 and 17))
GROUP BY S.SiteCode,
    S.Name,
    L.Name,
    DATEADD(HOUR, (T.Period)+1, P.DateData)
ORDER BY S.SiteCode,
        S.Name,
        L.Name,
        DATEADD(HOUR, (T.Period)+1, P.DateData)';
print @sql

--EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```